# Question about setting the MPPT on BQ24650

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller, mppt

I have a question about the MPPT in [BQ24650](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24650.pdf?ts=1601794897709&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) chip.

It has the `MPPTSET` pin that need to get 1.2v because the inside comparator.

According to the datasheet, on `page 13 section 8.3.2`, they say:

> When the voltage sensed on the MPPSET pin drops below 1.2 V, the charger maintains the input voltage by reducing the charge current. t. If the MPPSET pin voltage is forced below 1.2 V, the BQ24650
> stays in the input voltage regulation loop while the output current is zero

And on the other hand on `page 18 section 8.3.18` they say:

> MPPSET is used to disable or enable the charge process. A voltage above 175 mV on this pin enables charge. A voltage below 75 mV on this pin also resets all timers and fault conditions

My question is if the MPPTSET pin, senses a voltage so `175mv < Vmpptset` the charging is enabled.
But they also say that if `Vmpptset < 1.2v`, the output current will be zero. and the batteries will not charged.

What will happen when `175mV < Vmpptset < 1.2V`? the charge will be enabled and output current is zero?

It seems a bit weird or Im missing something..

Comment: Did you ask this question yesterday too?

Comment: Actually 3 days ago, but this one more accurate about the voltage range of the MPPT pin. I deleted the former question since it was too long and more general. I hope its ok..

Comment: It's OK. I meant to go back and try and answer, but couldn't find it later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what it says.

With Vmpptset < 1.2V, (but > 175mV) it will try to maintain the input voltage at (some setpoint defined somewhere) by reducing the charge current. If even reducing the current to 0 isn't enough to maintain Vin, it will stay in that state (but fail to maintain Vin).

So what happens is that it will keep trying to charge, but at a lower current than the current setpoint, as long as Vin remains at the voltage setpoint. But if there isn't enough sunlight to maintain Vin even with 0 current, it will remain in that state but at 0 current, waiting for more light.

Or

> A voltage above 175 mV on this pin enables charge

Charge is enabled, but what you get depends on the available current. But if there's not enough sunlight even to maintain Vin (at that setpoint) at 0 current, there's not a lot it can do.

This is not really MPPT as generally understood (the "T" means Tracking whereas this follows a pre-determined path): a poor man's MPPT if you will. I've seen a bunch of really cheap Chinese charge controllers that claim "MPPT" : presumably they use this chip or something similar.

Reading it a little further, the setpoint is defined by a voltage divider connected to MPPTSET. So if your solar panel claims its MPPT point is at (say) 16V at standard illumination, set the voltage divider to produce 1.2V from 16V.

Above 16V from the solar cell, you'll get constant current, to protect the battery.

Below 16V (1.2V at MPPset) a simple voltage divider will give you whatever current is available that keeps the cell producing close to 16V as long as Vin > Vbatt.

You could manipulate MPPset to try and discover the real MPPT; that would require external electronics, but may increase charging current by a few % in poor light.

Also note discrepancy between "To disable charge, pull MPPSET below 75 mV." on p.4 and 175mV on figure 8.2 p.12.
8.3.2 p.14 explains this as 100 mV hysteresis, 75mV to stop charging, 175 mV to restart.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, most of the time the controller will be on that stage of under 1.2v. because if Vin is 9v (Vmax power) for example and for some reason the voltage drops to 8.9v (small cloud \ shadow etc..), Vmpptset will sense  immediately voltage less than 1.2v. it means that if I dont want the controller to reduce current, 100% of the time the solar panel should get direct sun? I guess 9v its the set point you mentioned..

Comment: Is it valid to say that this controller is "true MPPT" only for 25 degrees celsius?

Comment: Not even that. At light below whatever produces your choice of Vin, the current will be reduced to try to maintain Vin, even though the true MPP point at below standard illumination will happen at a lower Vin and slightly higher current.

Comment: I see, you made it more clear :) about the first comment, is it correct that most of the time  the Vmpptset will be less than 1.2v?

Comment: Not sure, still reading. My take is that depends how you choose R3,R4, which select Vin to match your panel.  In full sun it should remain above 1.2V, in the constant current stage (unless you have a HUGE battery and high charge current) but I can see various ways to get just a bit more out of it.

Comment: I see.. do you familiar maybe with a "real" MPPT device? for home project, charging 2S Li-Ion batteries pack?

Comment: For your app I'd say this one is fine, I wouldn't worry about the last few %.